# Chat for iOS SDK

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

I am implementing QuickBlox chat for my iOS app. But I am not sure how can I get a list of all online users. It is a peer-to-peer chat only, not a chat room sort of thing. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Sample with docs for you!
http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a list of all online users in the app.

You can use a Contact List API to create own friends list and track online status of your friends http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Contact_list